# openscad conditional translate - #if #else #endif

Tags: openscad

As I type "openscad conditional" the google is having one of the top searches ending with "translate", but to my astonishment there're no documents matching this subject.

The problem: translating the cube under normal conditions, and not translating it under special conditions. You may suggest - just change xyz of the translate. But is it possible to cancel operator at all? Like

```
#if variable=1
    translate([1,1,1])
#else
    translate([2,2,2])
#endif
        cube([10,10,10]);
```

The top level problem I am trying to solve is having relatively complex drawing being totally repositioned and even rotated depending on the variable value. For this I need a number of movements being cancelled or adjusted and command like `rotate` added into the equation.

**Edit:** slightly better example:

```
if(variable==1) c=[10,10,10]; else c=[20,20,20];
translate(c)
    cube([10,10,10]);
```

At least defining xyz not separately but in the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `(condition ? case1 : case2)` block. When evaluated, it takes the `case1` value if the condition is respected and the `case2` value if it's not. So you can write :

```
translate(variable==1 ? [10,10,10] : [20,20,20])
    cube([10,10,10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as is.  Translate needs to be applied to an object.  Test this.

```
variable = 0;
if (variable == 1)
{
    translate([1,1,1])
        cube([10,10,10]);
}
else
{
    translate([2,2,2])
        cube([10,10,10]);
}
```

Consider putting your translate/cube into a module then call it with different arguments based on the value of the variable.

Comment: thought about it, and it will work if you use if without #. But this code means duplicating all the cubes.

Comment: Eh.  depend on what you are actually trying to do.  Keep in mind there is no c preprocessor,  and this is functional programming.  Consider  putting your translate/cube into a module then call it with different arguments based on the value of the variable

Comment: Put your comment into the answer, and I will accept it.